# Went to or went into in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

> Given: They looked for him in the forest.
>
> Question:  Where did they go in search of him?
>
> Possible Answers:
>
> 1.They went to the forest in search of him.
>
> 2.They went into the forest in search of him.

**If both are correct, what will be the difference between "to" and "into" in this sentence?**

Answer (score 1):

"They went to the forest" describes getting from where they were outside the forest to the edge of the forest.

"They went into the forest" describes moving from the edge of the forest to inside the forest.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but the more accurate answer would be "They went **into** the forest", because the person they're searching for is already **in** the forest.

Going **to** the forest only implies that they were in the general vicinity, but didn't necessarily enter the forest to look around.